# System design for url shortener

Tags: architecture, system-design

In the constraints video of https://www.hiredintech.com/classrooms/system-design/lesson/55, the narrator has to estimate the requests per month that should be handled. 
After reaching a figure of 100 MLN new urls per month to be generated (as a result of shortening), he states the following approximations:-

1) Each url has an average lifetime of 2 weeks

2) 20% urls generate 80 % traffic

With the above in mind , he did some 'quick math' and came to a figure of **1 BN request per month** to be handled.

Can someone say how he calculated such a figure?

Comment: @cosmos234
     Kindly care to accept my answer plz ?

Answer (score 1):

@cosmos234

Now you can find the details in [my deductions](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antonrd/hiredintech_files/master/system_design/digram_url_shortening.jpg) published on HiredIntech.
On the same page search by:

> UPDATE: Arnab Dutta sent us a great diagram with alternative ways to
>   estimate the requests per month. You can find it here.

Answer (score -1):

[Design a URL shortner](https://www.educative.io/collection/page/5668639101419520/5649050225344512/5668600916475904) here you can find detailed explanation of each calculations.

Comment: It doesnt help the OP